# T-SQL WHERE statement in function of parameter

Tags: t-sql, where-clause

I have the following table:

```
TABLE1
| ID | NAME   | TYPE  | COLOR  |
|  1 | APPLE  | FRUIT | RED    |
|  2 | BANANA | FRUIT | YELLOW |
|  3 | LEMON  | FRUIT | YELLOW |
|  4 | TOMATO | VEGET | RED    |
|  5 | PEPPER | VEGET | RED    |
|  6 | PEAR   | FRUIT | GREEN  |
```

And the input fields @TYPE and @COLOR.
If `@TYPE = '*'` and `@COLOR = '*'` then:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
```

otherwise, if `@TYPE = 'VEGET'` and `@COLOR = '*'`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TYPE = 'VEGET'
```

if `@TYPE = '*'` and `@COLOR = 'YELLOW'`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE COLOR = 'YELLOW'
```

and the last case, if `@TYPE = 'VEGET'` and `@COLOR = 'YELLOW'`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TYPE = 'VEGET'
AND COLOR = 'YELLOW'
```

Obviously it is not just two fields or parameters...
How can I write an efficient query to check all cases?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE 
   (TYPE = @TYPE OR @TYPE='*')
AND
   (COLOR = @COLOR OR @COLOR='*')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are filtering by many values, you can build dynamic `T-SQL` statement. For example:

1. First declare the basic statement:

   ```
   DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

   SET @DynamicSQLStatement = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE1'
   ```
2. Then check if a filtering is applied (if yes, add `WHERE`):

   ```
   IF @Type <> '*' OR <> @Color <> '*' OR ...
   BEGIN;
       SET @DynamicSQLStatement =  @DynamicSQLStatement + ' WHERE 1=1 ';
   END;
   ```
3. Then add check for each parameter:

   ```
   IF @Type <> '*' 
   BEGIN;
       SET @DynamicSQLStatement =  @DynamicSQLStatement + ' AND @Type = ' + @Type; 
   END;

   IF @Color <> '*' 
   BEGIN;
       SET @DynamicSQLStatement =  @DynamicSQLStatement + ' AND @Color = ' + @Color; 
   END;
   ```
4. Finally, execute the statement:

   ```
   EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQLStatement;
   ```

It's nice because in the final statement only the filtering that is specified is included. In some complicated filtering scenarios this can improve performance.

Few important notes:

- you are not allowed to use this in function, only stored procedure (which is limitation);
- you need to escape single quotes in strings (using double single quotes)
- if your parameter value is a number, you need to cast it to string